# Automatically export/deployment for Eclipse plugins

Tags: maven, ant, eclipse-plugin, auto-build

We are working on an Eclipse plugin project. All of our deliverables are 25 plug-in files (yes, you can also say that they are 25 jar files or 25 OSGi bundles).

Every time we export those files by `File` → `Export` → `Plug-in Development` → `Deployable plug-ins and fragments`. It costs about 30 minutes to export all those files. The export way sounds like out-of-date but not so inconvenient.

And I have some doubts about the exporting/deployment:

1. If we use a build tool (such as ANT or Maven) to build these jar files automatically, will the build tool reduce the whole exporting time ?
2. The PDE can generate a ant build file by `Plug-in Tools` → `Create Ant Build File`, so can we use those generated files directly, even without start up the elipse IDE? Since they seem to be eclipse-related.
3. Its better if you have suggestions on what I'm saying.

Tks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [tycho](http://eclipse.org/tycho/) is what you need. Tycho is a maven plugin for building osgi bundles(and eclipse plugins)

Answer (score 0):

While eclipse plugins can be shared and delivered, they are not meant to be used as deliverables. Instead you should create an [eclipse feature](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/concepts/feature.htm), which combines the plugins into one single installable unit.

Comment: Tks,@Bananeweizen.But the point on this question is build/export for plugins.I'm just curious about if the traditional auto-build tool(ant or maven)can be used in Eclipse plugin exporting,or if there is a better way.

Comment: No. The point is that you are creating non working deliverables, as your export (and copy deployment) cannot check for plugin dependencies, and therefore will only work by luck of the user having those dependencies installed. You are basically asking where to get a faster car, while I'm telling you that you don't know some important driving rules yet. The building time will still be many minutes with Maven/Tycho, but you can easily automate Tycho builds on a continuous integration server, so you don't have to wait: http://alexander.holbreich.org/2012/02/eclipse-tycho-build/

Comment: The exported plugins will be running on a same target platform just as the development environment,and this is required by our clients.So we don't need to focus on the plugin dependency issues and that's the reason we wont have a car accident.But still,as we are lacking of experience in continuous integration for plugin-dev,the simple `export` cant be automated.